# Is it possible to view logs in the spark history server with spark.eventLog.compress enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I would like to enable `spark.eventLog.compress` in an EMR cluster to save log space without losing functionality from the spark history server. I've tried enabling the configuration setting and submitting a basic step, but with it turned on the history server just shows "No completed applications found!". No incomplete applications are found either. Running an identical cluster with `spark.eventLog.compress` set to false shows the application logs I would expect.

The logs do appear to be there and compressed

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.history.fs.logDirectory")
res0: String = hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps

scala> :quit
[hadoop@ip-... ~]$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
Found 3 items
-rwxrwx---   1 hadoop spark      24595 2020-12-07 22:26 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1607379760026_0001_1.lz4
-rwxrwx---   1 hadoop spark      17878 2020-12-07 22:26 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1607379760026_0002.lz4
-rwxrwx---   1 hadoop spark      12190 2020-12-07 22:44 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1607379760026_0003.lz4
[hadoop@ip-... ~]$ logout
```

I also tried checking the logs from the `org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer` process (found through `ps aux | grep -i history`) by following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308666/329817)

```
[hadoop@ip-... ~]$ sudo tail -f /proc/25275/fd/1
...
20/12/08 20:46:08 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0002_1.lz4 to re-build UI...
20/12/08 20:46:08 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0002_1.lz4
20/12/08 21:01:50 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0003_1.lz4.inprogress for listing data...
20/12/08 21:01:50 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0003_1.lz4.inprogress
20/12/08 21:02:00 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0003_1.lz4 for listing data...
20/12/08 21:02:00 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://ip-...:8020/var/log/spark/apps/application_1607443436753_0003_1.lz4
```

which seems to me to suggest that the history server should be able to read them, but it is hard to say whether I'm just missing an error message or something. **Is it possible to view logs in the history server with `spark.eventLog.compress` enabled?**

Comment: Can you share what you have set in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark_default.conf and also your spark-submit command

Answer (score 1):

**spark.eventLog.compress=true** - Yes, you can view the event logs in Spark History Server UI but if you want to read the content from file directly not possible because it is compressed.

- spark.eventLog.compress (Default false) - Whether to enable (true) or disable (false) event compression (using a CompressionCodec).
- spark.eventLog.compression.codec (Default none) - A codec for compressing log events. By default, Spark provides four types of codecs: LZ4, LZF, Snappy, and ZSTD. If this parameter is not specified, spark.io.compression.codec is used.